# Rotating a Spirte Rectangle 90 degrees doesn't repect aspect ratio in iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es

am working in a OpenGL ES 2.0 game, in iOS platform using basically C++. And I wanted to implement both both portrait and landscape orientation doing a 90 degrees rotation.

The problem I have is very simple. I have one sprite that is in one rectangle and if I do a rotation of 90 degrees and expected to see the same figure rotated.

The problem I have is that is a noticeable difference in the figure, both in aspect ratio and size.

In one orientation:
8.4 cm x 5.0 cm

The other:
7.6 cm x 5.4 cm

I wonder if it that is posible be casued by errors caused by float machine representation? Has someone had also that problem?

In the first test I do:

```
glm::mat4 ProjModelViewMatrix = glm::ortho<float>(-1.0, +1.0, -1.5f, 1.5f);

/// DRAW CODE
```

In the second test I ONLY add a rotation matrix:

```
glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), -PI_F / 2.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));

glm::mat4 ProjModelViewMatrix = glm::ortho<float>(-1.0, +1.0, -1.5f, 1.5f) * rotation;

/// DRAW CODE
```

Just in case:
ALL THE vertices are in the plane z=0.
The sprite is mapped in a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it that is possible be caused by errors caused by float
>   machine representation?

If you are running this on the CPU with fp32 calculations it's very very unlikely - you'd need a a large absolute error to get that much size change on screen, and floating point error doesn't accumulate that quickly in only a handful of multiplies.

Couple of ideas:

- What are the values in the 4x4 rotation matrix?
- Matrix multiplication is order sensitive - are you multiplying the together in the right order? I'm not sure how glm lays out its matrices in memory, so you may be correct here.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the reason. I was thinking that the iOS device has  2:3 aspect ratio and in fact it is 3:4 !